# How can i stop this image from moving?

Tags: php, html, css, web

I'm updating my work website using Joomla - I've been given the old copy and I need to improve it. (The website is [24x7cloud.co.uk](http://www.24x7cloud.co.uk)) towards the bottom I want to create an "Accreditation's" section, however, every time I  add this section it affects my "Contact Us" section which is below it. (Attached screenshots to show)

The grey overlay should go over the whole image and the image shouldn't be stretched so far down. It should cut off where the grey goes across the telephone box. It's like this when the section above is not there, but as soon as I create it - it pushes the image and creates this effect...

[The Orange scribble is the part that is broken. That part of the scribble shouldn't be there. It should cut off where the grey banner stops](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqEjG.jpg)

[What the website should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TvFw.jpg)

[What it looks like when adding a new section above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HW2z.jpg)

This is the HTML for the "Contact Us"

```css
/* ==== 18) Contact Details ==== */

#contact {
  background-position: center 0%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(../img/bg_8.jpg);
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  vertical-align: middle;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #121212;
}

.details {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 3;
}

.phone-info {
  line-height: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-top: 0px;
}

.blah a {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
}


/* Overlay on contact us */


}
.parallax-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(../img/pattern.png);
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-color: rgba(44, 62, 80, 0.6);
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="details col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="margin-top:60px;">
</div>

<div class="details col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="margin-top:60px;">

  <h2>Contact us</h2>
  <p class="lead">We would love to work with you!</p>

  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center">
    <h3><small class="white"><a href="callto:+443302231042" style="color:#FFFFFF;"><i class="icon ion-ios7-telephone ion-1x white"></i> 0330 223 1042</a></small></h3>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center blah">
    <h4>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        <!--
        var x = "function f(x){var i,o=\"\",ol=x.length,l=ol;while(x.charCodeAt(l/13)!" +
          "=92){try{x+=x;l+=l;}catch(e){}}for(i=l-1;i>=0;i--){o+=x.charAt(i);}return o" +
          ".substr(0,ol);}f(\")621,\\\"6<0#+6f)9ov,ncP220\\\\020\\\\720\\\\730\\\\230\\" +
          "\\430\\\\220\\\\400\\\\5000\\\\020\\\\320\\\\500\\\\630\\\\000\\\\r\\\\SN71" +
          "30\\\\<H310\\\\710\\\\400\\\\)Cr\\\\5@4=40030\\\\x500\\\\e2:!='rs410\\\\;-," +
          "8%%n\\\\h\\\"\\\\2,7!'620\\\\}K]XVYOJ700\\\\\\\\\\\\C330\\\\[P430\\\\^\\\\\\" +
          "\\CKNHNXi\\\\\\\\DGQJLA330\\\\Okrt}v8E%qsg|3s-2'`ai771\\\\c{771\\\\)rkanwbo" +
          "230\\\\\\\"(f};o nruter};))++y(^)i(tAedoCrahc.x(edoCrahCmorf.gnirtS=+o;721=" +
          "%y{)++i;l<i;0=i(rof;htgnel.x=l,\\\"\\\"=o,i rav{)y,x(f noitcnuf\")";
        while (x = eval(x));
        //-->
        //]]>
      </script>
    </h4>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center">
    <h4><small class="white"><a target="_self" href="http://www.redcello.co.uk/index.php?option=com_rsform&view=rsform&formId=6" style="color:#FFFFFF;">Click here for a call back</a></small></h4>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2" style="padding-top:20px;">

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
      <div class="about-icon" style="display:block; width:100%;">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/RedcelloUK">
          <i class="icon ion-social-twitter ion-3x white"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
      <div class="about-icon" style="display:block; width:100%;">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/redcello">
          <i class="icon ion-social-linkedin ion-3x white"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
      <div class="about-icon" style="display:block; width:100%;">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/RedcelloUK">
          <i class="icon ion-social-facebook ion-3x white"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Not sure if this is helpful, but here is the element from firefox:

```
    <section id="contact" data-stellar-background-ratio="1.0" data-stellar-vertical-offset="" style="background-position: 50% 0px;" class="current">
                      <div class="row text-center" style="position:relative;">
                         <div class="parallax-overlay"></div> 
                            <div class="container content">
                        <div class="moduletable">


<div class="custom">
    <div class="details col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="margin-top:60px;">
</div>

<div class="details col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="margin-top:60px;">

  <h2>Contact us</h2>
   <p class="lead">We would love to work with you!</p>

<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center">
<h3><small class="white"><a href="callto:+443302231042" style="color:#FFFFFF;"><i class="icon ion-ios7-telephone ion-1x white"></i> 0330 223 1042</a></small></h3>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center blah">
    <h4> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
<!--
var x="function f(x){var i,o=\"\",ol=x.length,l=ol;while(x.charCodeAt(l/13)!" +
"=92){try{x+=x;l+=l;}catch(e){}}for(i=l-1;i>=0;i--){o+=x.charAt(i);}return o" +
".substr(0,ol);}f(\")621,\\\"6<0#+6f)9ov,ncP220\\\\020\\\\720\\\\730\\\\230\\"+
"\\430\\\\220\\\\400\\\\5000\\\\020\\\\320\\\\500\\\\630\\\\000\\\\r\\\\SN71" +
"30\\\\<H310\\\\710\\\\400\\\\)Cr\\\\5@4=40030\\\\x500\\\\e2:!='rs410\\\\;-," +
"8%%n\\\\h\\\"\\\\2,7!'620\\\\}K]XVYOJ700\\\\\\\\\\\\C330\\\\[P430\\\\^\\\\\\"+
"\\CKNHNXi\\\\\\\\DGQJLA330\\\\Okrt}v8E%qsg|3s-2'`ai771\\\\c{771\\\\)rkanwbo" +
"230\\\\\\\"(f};o nruter};))++y(^)i(tAedoCrahc.x(edoCrahCmorf.gnirtS=+o;721=" +
"%y{)++i;l<i;0=i(rof;htgnel.x=l,\\\"\\\"=o,i rav{)y,x(f noitcnuf\")"          ;
while(x=eval(x));
//-->
//]]>
    </script><a href="mailto:contact@redcello.co.uk?subject=Website Contact" title="Click To Mail Us">contact@redcello.co.uk</a>

    </h4> 
    </div>

<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center">
<h4><small class="white"><a target="_self" href="http://www.redcello.co.uk/index.php?option=com_rsform&amp;view=rsform&amp;formId=6" style="color:#FFFFFF;">Click here for a call back</a></small></h4>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2" style="padding-top:20px;">

<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
   <div class="about-icon" style="display:block; width:100%;">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/RedcelloUK">
        <i class="icon ion-social-twitter ion-3x white"></i>
        </a>
     </div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
   <div class="about-icon" style="display:block; width:100%;">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/redcello">
    <i class="icon ion-social-linkedin ion-3x white"></i>
        </a>
     </div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
   <div class="about-icon" style="display:block; width:100%;">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/RedcelloUK">
    <i class="icon ion-social-facebook ion-3x white"></i>
        </a>
     </div>
</div>

</div>

</div></div>
        </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                   </section>
```

Sorry for the bunch of code - I wanted to make sure I got everything that is needed to help. After trying multiple times - I cannot for the life of me solve this. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Use z-index: -1; to your image css property

Answer (score 0):

Change the `#contact` `z-index:1` to `z-index:-1;`

```
#contact {
  background-position: center 0%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(../img/bg_8.jpg);
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  vertical-align: middle;
  z-index: -1;
  color: #121212;
}
```

This will get the image behind the text (one layer behind).

Reference 
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't fix the problem :(

Comment: Try changing your #contact{ z-index: -1} and keep the .parallax-overlay as z-index:2. Sorry about that I can't test your code online. It doesn't apply image background from css to html.

Comment: Still doesn't seem to fix the issue. I've attached another photo to the main post to try and explain what i mean

Comment: Oh right, try changing the grey banner part to position: absolute?

Comment: They grey part is the parallax-overlay. Which is set to absolute already :(

Comment: .parallax-overlay {

position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 1000;
  margin-bottom: -20px;} Try this

Comment: after doing that it removes the horizontal grey overlay completely. What I need is basically to chop the background image in half so the image stops when the grey horizontal line finishes..

Comment: So that means it moves over image right? then try .parallax-overlay { position: relative; z-index: 1000; margin-top: 60px;}

Comment: Still not working :( - If you go to 24x7cloud.co.uk and scroll to the bottom - I've removed the section above which removes this problem. That is what the contact us part should look like... Every time I add the module above the contact us, it's like it stops the image from being cut off and it just continues